# What is the difference between Outlook Cached Mode and the Download Option in Send/Receive Settings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, cached-exchange-mode

In Outlook 2013, I have Cached Mode set to All, for an Exchange account.  In Options, Advanced, Send/Receive Settings the Exchange account has Include Selected Account unchecked and Folder Options at the bottom is, of course, grayed out.  If I check it, the Folder Options allow changing.

Folder Options says, "Select folders from the selected account to include in send/receive.  Complete items including attachments will be downloaded for subscribed folders."

Many of the folders for the user are not checked.

If I put the Outlook 2013 client in Cached Mode -> All, does it automatically get everything?  Is anything left out?  What are the Send/Receive settings for if I am using Cached mode?

Is this for limiting Cached mode, even though I have it set to "All"?

Answer (score 2):

When you put Outlook 2013 in cached mode, it will ask you how much you want to cache. By default this is 12 months. It can be changed to everything or less.

Because this by default is not everything, there is this option to download everything once for the selected account/folder etc.

Comment: What are the send/receive settings for?

Comment: Send/receive just triggers getting the latest mail.